# What's the best way to create a new design for other pages?

Tags: theme-development

I want to create a different design for all new and existing pages, with the exception of the frontpage.

The new design includes another subheader, container, and an extra subfooter.

My guess was to edit footer.php/header.php in my child theme directly, and create seperate subheader/footer/container for these pages, and apply them as follows:

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page()){
<div class="subheader_front"></div>                     
            }
else {     
<div class="subheader"></div>
} ?>
```

Is this a correct way of applying a new design, or could this be done simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create template files named `front-page.php` and `home.php`, which will be automatically loaded.  See the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) for details.

You can also set up different headers for different template files.  For instance, if you have a Home Page template `home.php`, you can have a separate header file loaded in it.

In your `home.php` file, you can pass a parameter to your [`get_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) call -- for example, `get_header( 'home' )`.  This will look for a file named `header-home.php`, and load it if it exists.  Failing that, it will load the default `header.php` file instead.  You can do the same with your `get_footer()` and `get_sidebar()` calls.

#### Codex Pages

[Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)
[`get_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header)
[`get_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar)
[`get_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer)

Comment: You can do a lot with the Template Hierarchy.  It's an amazing system.

Comment: just to make it clear, I don't have a home.php or front-page.php at this moment. As I don't use the blog, I would have to create a front-page.php. In this page I put get_header() etc. Then It will automatically be loaded as the frontpage. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, if you create a file called `front-page.php`, it will be used as your site's front page.  I usually copy `page.php` to `front-page.php` and then make the necessary modifications to `front-page.php` (ie, header, footer, content, etc.).

Comment: Ok, thx Pat! You're the best!